# Lag back to a Value with Conditions R

Tags: r, data-cleaning, lag

I am in need of a conditional way to lag back to the last row where the value is one number or "level" lower than the current row. Whenever type = "yes", I want to go back one level lower to the last "no" and get the quantity. For example, rows 2 and 3 here are type "yes" and level 5. In that case, I'd like to go back to the last level 4 "no" row, get the quantity, and assign it to a new column. When type is "no" no lagging needs to be done.

```
Data:

row_id  level  type   quantity
1       4      no     100
2       5      yes    110
3       5      yes    115
4       2      no     500  
5       2      no     375
6       3      yes    250
7       3      yes    260
8       3      yes    420


Desired output:

row_id  level  type  quantity lagged_quantity
1       4      no    100      NA
2       5      yes   110      100
3       5      yes   115      100
4       2      no    500      NA
5       2      no    375      NA
6       3      yes   250      375
7       3      yes   260      375
8       3      yes   420      375

Data:

structure(list(row_id = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8), level = c(4, 
5, 5, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3), type = c("no", "yes", "yes", "no", "no", 
"yes", "yes", "yes"), quantity = c(100, 110, 115, 500, 375, 250, 
260, 420)), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))


Desired output:

structure(list(row_id = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8), level = c(4, 
5, 5, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3), type = c("no", "yes", "yes", "no", "no", 
"yes", "yes", "yes"), quantity = c(100, 110, 115, 500, 375, 250, 
260, 420), lagged_quantity = c("NA", "100", "100", "NA", "NA", 
"375", "375", "375")), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

@Mossa

Comment: Please use `dput` to provide the code to create both the input data-frame, and the desired output data-frame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Direct solution would be to:

```r
df1 %>% 
  mutate(
    level_id = 1 + cumsum(c(1, diff(level)) < 0)
  ) %>%
  mutate(lagged_quantity = if_else(type == "yes", NA_real_, quantity)) %>% 
  fill(lagged_quantity) %>% 
  mutate(lagged_quantity = if_else(type == "no", NA_real_, lagged_quantity))
```

Where first we retain only the values you would like, and then the missing entries are filled with last known value, and then the `no` answers, that need not be lagged, are taken out.

Answer (score 1):

An option with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[df1[, .(lagged_qty = last(quantity)), .(level, type)][,
   lagged_qty := shift(lagged_qty), .(grp = cumsum(type == 'no'))], 
    lagged_qty := lagged_qty, on = .(level, type)]
```

-output

```
> df1
   row_id level   type quantity lagged_qty
    <int> <int> <char>    <int>      <int>
1:      1     4     no      100         NA
2:      2     5    yes      110        100
3:      3     5    yes      115        100
4:      4     2     no      500         NA
5:      5     2     no      375         NA
6:      6     3    yes      250        375
7:      7     3    yes      260        375
8:      8     3    yes      420        375
```